# Parse a custom tag using request information in JSP

Tags: jsp, parameters, jakarta-ee, request, custom-tag

I have a simple problem but I haven't had any luck finding the solution with Google.

I want to expand custom JSP tags but I want to be able to parse it differently depending on request information. For example the tag:

```
<my:tag type="..."/>
```

Should be expanded differently if the parameters in the request differ:

```
http://localhost:8080/context/servlet?arg=web
```

Should yield a different result than:

```
http://localhost:8080/context/servlet?arg=mobile
```

Does anybody know how the tag parsing class (usually expands `TagSupport`) can access or be passed parameters from the request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside the tag class, you can access the request object and get the parameter by

```
this.pageContext.getRequest().getParameter("arg");
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [Expression Language](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/JSPIntro7.html#wp71043) to supply the request parameter to your JSP-Tag.

```
<my:tag type="${param.arg}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access it through the getParameter() method of HttpServletRequest object.

```
String arg1 = request.getParameter("arg");
```

There, you have the variable arg1 that contains "web" or "mobile" when hit from different URL as in your 2 examples.

Comment: I understand that but the request.getParameter method is not available from the context of a TagSupport class.